# Determine the bucket to which a number belongs to

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js, underscore.js, lodash

How do you determine the bucket to which a number belongs to? For ex, lets say we have buckets 0 - 20, 21 - 50, 51 - 80, 81 - 100 or the equivalent grades as 'Poor', 'Average', 'Good', 'Great'. Is there an efficient way using jquery/lodash/d3/underscore to find out that '45' belongs to the '21 - 50' bucket or is 'Average'?

Edit: Is this the best way to do it? In terms of speed, minimal code.

Here's what I have with a lot of help;

```
// Set up your data
var range = [[0, 20], [21, 50], [51, 80], [81, 100]]
var number = 45

range.find(function(val) { return val[1] >= number })
// Returns [21, 50]

range.findIndex(function(val) { return val[1] >= number })
// Returns 1
```

Comment: So whats the issue? Please be clear with your question

Comment: Did you need the bucket AND the grade, because you already can do bucket OR the grade

Comment: I just wanted to know if there is 'an efficient/better way' of doing this.

Comment: @richie _"I wanted to know if there is 'an efficient/better way' of doing this"_ What do you mean by "efficient" and "better"?

Comment: About ready to flag this as off topic / external resource, or off topic / opinion based

Comment: Might as well point it out, as it might help - you don't need to do both `find` and `findIndex` - if you just run `findIndex` you can use that result to lookup the associated bucket simply by doing `range[index]`. That would be a single array traversal (to find the appropriate bucket) as oppose to two. Also, I don't really think it's really useful here, but in general you can also use `_.inRange`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an array of objects with properties set to from `"Poor"` to `"Great"` corresponding to the range of numbers set as value of the property, `Array.prototype.filter()`

```js
var range = [{
  Poor: [0, 20]
}, {
  Average: [21, 50]
}, {
  Good: [51, 80]
}, {
  Great: [81, 100]
}];

var number = 45;

var res = range.filter(function(el) {
  var key = el[Object.keys(el)];
  return number > key[0] && number < key[1]
});

console.log(Object.keys(res[0])[0])
```

Comment: neat - I didn't think of altering the input range data

Comment: What is purpose of "downvote" without reason? How can the Answer be improved?

Answer (score 3):

This should work...

```js
var range = [[0, 20], [21, 50], [51, 80], [81, 100]]
var number = 45
var bucket = range.filter(function(a) {
  if (number >= a[0] && number <= a[1]) return a
})

console.log(bucket[0])
```

Comment: that wont tell you which position the bucket is in :D

Comment: The requirement is to return the bucket not the position.

Comment: actually the requirement is to determine the range (21-50) "or" the grade (average) ... I wonder if he meant AND, because he knows how to do OR

Comment: Yeah. So, I've a answer which returns the bucket not the index

Comment: @PraneshRavi he clearly does **OR** in the question -

Comment: `I've a answer which returns the bucket not the index` ... so does the OP - `range.find(function(val) { return val[1] >= number })`

Comment: @JaromandaX **minimal code** is the criteria. Also, you cannot simply change the input to make the code work.

Comment: @PraneshRavi - yet, that's exactly what the accepted answer is doing - how wrong

Comment: @PraneshRavi The OP's code could be re-written fairly easily to allow changing the input and would still be shorter than yours, so ... you don't really meet the minimal code criteria.  Also, I suspect meeting the "etc" criteria is going to prove challenging.

Answer (score 1):

The *D3 way* using scales:

```js
var scale = d3.scaleQuantize()
  .domain([0,100])
  .range(["very bad","bad","average","good","very good"]);

console.log(scale(34));
console.log(scale(55));
console.log(scale(91));
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
```

The nice thing of D3 is that the scale automatically divides the domain based on the number of values of the range. For instance, the snippet above has 5 values ("very bad","bad","average","good","very good"), and so 34 is "bad". In the snippet below, using only 3 values, 34 is "average":

```js
var scale = d3.scaleQuantize()
  .domain([0,100])
  .range(["bad","average","good"]);

console.log(scale(34));
console.log(scale(55));
console.log(scale(91));
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var ranges = [
    {
        name: 'Poor',
        range: [0, 20]
    },
    {
        name: 'Average',
        range: [21, 50]
    },
    {
        name: 'Good',
        range: [51, 80]
    },
    {
        name: 'Great',
        range: [81, 100]
    },
]
var number = 45;
var range = _.find(ranges, function (r) {
    return _.inRange(number, r.range[0], r.range[1] + 1);
}).name;
```